# Nextjs With Django Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: django, next.js, content-security-policy

In a project where Nextjs is used as a frontend and Django is used as a backend api, where should the Content Security Policy (CSP) be set? Ive seen in examples that csp rules can be set in nextjs in the next config file and in django it can be set in the settings.py

I am still trying to wrap my head around csp and security related things in general.
Not sure if this matters but I am not using the api features in Nextjs, only django as an api.

Answer (score 0):

To set a Content Security Policy (CSP) rule in a Next.js app, you'll need to do the following:

1. Create a _document.js file in the pages directory of your Next.js app if you don't already have one.
2. In the _document.js file, add the following line to the Head component to set the Content-Security-Policy header:

```
<Head>
  <meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="your CSP rule here" />
</Head>
```

and then just replace your CSP rule here with the actual CSP rule you want to set. For example, to block all inline scripts and styles, you could use the following rule:

```
"default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
```

save your changes and restart your Next.js application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know where to set the csp rules in nextjs. Im wondering if i should set it in nextjs, django or both

Comment: You can set the Content Security Policy (CSP) in either or both of the following places. It's generally a good idea to set the CSP rules in both the frontend and the backend to provide an additional layer of security for your application.